# Django admin - how to get all registered models in templatetag?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm writing a custom admin stuff and need to get all registered models in Admin. Is this possible? I need it to make some custom views on admin index page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can access `admin.site._registry` dict of Model->ModelAdmin:

```
>>> ./manage.py shell

In [1]: from urls import * # load admin

In [2]: from django.contrib import admin

In [3]: admin.site._registry
Out[3]: 
{django.contrib.auth.models.Group: <django.contrib.auth.admin.GroupAdmin at 0x22629d0>,
 django.contrib.auth.models.User: <django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin at 0x2262a10>,
 django.contrib.sites.models.Site: <django.contrib.sites.admin.SiteAdmin at 0x2262c90>,
 testapp.models.Up: <django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin at 0x2269c10>,
 nashvegas.models.Migration: <nashvegas.admin.MigrationAdmin at 0x2262ad0>}
```

This is what the admin index view does:

```
@never_cache
def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
    """ 
    Displays the main admin index page, which lists all of the installed
    apps that have been registered in this site.
    """
    app_dict = {}
    user = request.user
    for model, model_admin in self._registry.items():
        # ...
```

Note that variables prefixed with an underscore are potentially subject to changes in future versions of django.

Comment: Do You know if there's some method, to get actual app in which user is in admin? If it's dahsboard it returns no app, but for others it returns all label or object. I want to use it as templatetag in my admin global menu.

Comment: I don't understand, can you open another question and give more details ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from django.apps import apps

models = apps.get_models()

for model in models:
   try:
       my_custom_admin_site.register(model)
   except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
       pass
```

`apps.get_models()` will give all the registered models in the default Django Admin site.